# How to get bash autocompletion to mimic the behavior for a certain command?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readlink

I'm writing a script wrapping a certain Linux command. Now, that command, when I use it directly on the command-line, has some autocomplete behavior. For example, if I type the command name, then space, then a string and press Tab - it gets completed into the name of an executable on the path. However, the wrapper script does *not* seem to have this behavior. How can I get bash to use the same auto-completion for my wrapper as for the original command?

To make things more concrete: The command is `which`. I'm writing a wrapper which invokes it, and if it didn't fail, executes `readlink -f` on the result of `which`. I would like auto-complete to find the executable on the path, as it does for `which`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the completion spec for `which` with

```
complete -p which
```

The result is `complete -c which`. So if you have your own new command `mywhich`, executable, in the PATH, then you can have it complete in the same way by configuring bash with

```
complete -c mywhich
```

You can put this line in `~/.bash_completion`

Comment: That doesn't seem to  make a lot of sense, since supposedly it says that bash will run `which` in a subshell and use its output for completion

Comment: I must not have understood what you want to do. `complete -c <name-of-a-command>` is like `-A command` and means look through all the available commands (in PATH) to create the list of possible completions.

Comment: No, you have understood, it just looked like a kind of recursive thing: complete -switch something produces complete -switch something ...